# Is there a better way of copying constructor parameters to object properites?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

My class' constructor looks like this:

```
class Customer {
  constructor(params) {
    this.id = params.id;
    this.firstName = params.firstName;
    this.lastName = params.lastName;
  }
}
```

I like using named parameters (my object actually has more parameters than this).

In ECMAScript 2015/2016 is there a better way of assigning the variables than this?

Comment: [A shorter class initialisation in ECMAScript 6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33328202/2301450)

Comment: related: [One-liner to take some properties from object in ES6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25553910/1048572)

Comment: Is this a duplicate, given the other answers do not use named parameters?