# How to get function caller AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, callstack

I tried a few pure JS solutions, but they don't work with Angular (possibly because of $scope ?)

I have a common error reporting function, which will `console.error()` an error text & `alert()` it too.

I would also like it if the function could report the line number & the function name of the caller.

If it cannot be done *in* the function, then I suppose I could live with the caller adding these parameters, if they are available at that level.

Please note that there is not necessarily a JS error. I can call the function because I don't like the value of some of my data.

Comment: did u use `(new Error).lineNumber.`

Comment: and for function name use `arguments.callee.caller.name`

Comment: `console.log(arguments.callee.caller.name);` is blank (in Chrome) probably because of `$scope` which expands it to an anonymous function/ 
`console.log((new Error).lineNumber);` is blank (in Chrome)

Comment: Do you have particular problems with `error.stack`? Can you provide a verifiable example that shows what you're trying to do?

Comment: There is not necessarily a JS error. I can call the function because I don't like the value of some of my data.

Comment: I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/29572569/1559213 and always getting `compile` as output. seems like everything runs by angular compile function