# Typescript allowing for arguments.callee.name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

If we `"strict": false` in `tsconfig.json`, then we can access `arguments.callee.name`.

Is there some other setting that we can switch on, while keeping `"strict": true` to get the same effect?

I'd like to be as strict as possible, and no stricter.

Comment: typescript is transpiled into javascript, so no.

Comment: Plugging my own answer from a several years ago: [yeah it's possible, but ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29572569/1715579) and not entirely reliable -- I recommend against using it in prod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, buddy... either you want to be strict, or not.  arguments.callee was deprecated a decade ago.  What is the problem you are trying to solve?  Except for very specific circumstances there are better ways to deal with that...

Comment: Thanks @LeroyStav.  I'm creating a custom Error and want to include the method name that threw the exception, and instead of writing it myself, I figured javascript could just grab it for me ... but apparently it's tricky :)

Comment: If you just want to debug your code, why don't you print a stacktrace?

Comment: Actually, thats pretty much what p.s.w.g describes in his comment's link... you can parse the stack trace from the Error object that is thrown.  put a breakpoint there and see what properties are available and figure out what works for you