# Is there a production safe version of Function.caller in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, strict, backtrace

Is there a way to return the function that invoked the current function? [Function.caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) will only work for non-strict mode applications.

I want to be able to use this functionality for production environment, therefore I need strict mode to be turned on.

Expected return: function itself or the name of function.

```
function a() {
 b()
}

function b() {
 console.log(b.caller)
}
```

[Function.caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) will throw an error when used in strict mode:

Uncaught TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them

Comment: Check the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29572569/6080889

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you using it for?

Comment: @Royson the suggested answer [`error.stack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack) which is non-standard

Comment: @CodeManiac So do you know any "standard" solution for this? Without having to pass the caller name in a parameter each time?

Comment: You should have written "production-safe version", with the hyphen. This is the rule for compound adjectives (words that are combined together to describe another, following word).

Answer (score 7):

One possible way is use [`Console.trace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console#Stack_traces)

```js
function a() {
 b()
}

function b() {
 console.trace()
}

a()
```

Check the browser console to see output

Comment: And what to do when I want to use the data for other purposes instead of showing it in the console? (Since you say "one possible way", I assume there are other ways as well?...)

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be a flexible way of doing that natively in JavaScript.

When using a non-standard solution might be acceptable, you could look into the [`Error.prototype.stack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack) property. You could use the method in [p.s.w.g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1715579)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572466/29572569#29572569), as [Royson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6080889) already suggested in a comment.

For a more robust solution for production use, I think you should consider using an external package (like [stacktrace.js](https://www.stacktracejs.com/)).